# Perl Regex either some string is there or not

Tags: regex, perl

today i need your help again.
Im learning Perl and my first Job is to expand a little script which waits for this Output from a virtual machine this output is:

```
Info: SOME_RANDOM_STRING: Focus switched to: [b] (1)
```

OR

```
Info: Focus switched to: [b] (1)
```

So the "SOME_RANDOM_STRING:" can be there but doesn't need to now i need to match those to decide if the Output was there or not. I tried

```
Info: [a-zA-Z0-9*:]* Focus switched to: [b] (1)
```

And this matches "Info: SOME_RANDOM_STRING: Focus switched to: [b] (1)" but not "Info: Focus switched to: [b] (1)"

Comment: all your input strings appear to be the same :)

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry i dont get it.

Comment: It's confusing, what is your regex, what are your input strings? what are expected results?  Where is your code?

Comment: I will edit the question to make it clear. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to capture one of the two spaces enclosing your random string.

This does not match any space at all:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9:]*
```

Use this instead:

```
( [a-zA-Z0-9:]+)?
```

Comment: First try is positive now it matches without "SOME_RANDOM_STRING:" now i will try with SOME_RANDOM_STRING:

Answer (score 1):

I'd do:

```
$str =~ /Info:.*?Focus switched to: \[b\] \(1\)/;
```

Where `.*?` matches any number of any character not greedy.

Comment: Even if i already had a valid answer i tried your's too, works thanks